# How to make selected alert pop up when selected index was choosen

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make if selected index in option was choosen then the selected alert is pop up, but I don't know how to do it, here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    function check1(){
       var e= document.getElementById("maske");
       var selec= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
       if(document.selec.value==1){
           alert("Minta tambahan gaji");
       }
    }
```

My html code:

```
<select name="masalah_keuangan" id="maske">
<option value="1">Gaji terlalu sedikit</option>
</select>
<button name="button1" onclick="check1();">Enter</button>
```

I want if the option value is 1, then the `alert("Minta tambahan gaji")` pops up

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to have to get the value of the option (select) and after the if condition, show the alert:

```js
function check1(){
   var theElement = document.getElementById("maske");
   var selectedOption = theElement.options[theElement.selectedIndex].value;
   if(selectedOption==1){
     alert(theElement.options[theElement.selectedIndex].text);
   }
}
```

```html
<select name="masalah_keuangan" id="maske">
 <option value="1">Gaji terlalu sedikit</option>
 <option value="2">Text 2</option>
 <option value="3">Text 3</option>
 <option value="4">Text 4</option>
</select>
<button name="button1" onclick="check1();">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Function should be like below

```
function check1(){
   var e = document.getElementById("maske");
   var selec = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
   if(selec==1){
     alert(e.options[e.selectedIndex].text);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it